# Is there a reason to ever use Constants instead of Messages?

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization

I want to internationlize my GWT application. After reading the docs, I can't see a reason to ever use Constants instead of Messages. Messages seem to be more powerful in every regard.

Is there any reason to ever use constants? Do they have better performance or any other advantage over Messages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Messages is only about strings, while Constants can contain numbers, booleans, arrays of strings, etc.

[Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/f0iYG7eAp24)

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily a reason to not use Messages but there is a difference worth noting. When using the Messages interface, strings defined in .properties files that contain single quotes (') need to be escaped. When using the Constants interface this isn't necessary. For example if you have the following interface:

MyMessages.java

```
public interface MyMessages extends Messages {
    @DefaultMessage("Please")
    String please();
}
```

MyMessages_fr.properties

```
# this will throw a java.text.ParseException: Unterminated single quote 
please = S'il vous plaît

# this will be parsed correctly and will display with only 1 single quote
please = S''il vous plaît
```